# Avoid exception when quering an empty facebook query

Tags: java, exception, facebook-fql

Using facebook fql, sometimes when there are no posts on my page that satisfy the query below, the query will return an empty message string, how can I avoid an exception in this case.

**code:**

```
String query = "SELECT message,timeline_visibility, created_time   FROM stream WHERE source_id = 187050104663230 AND message AND strlen(attachment.fb_object_type) < 1 AND type != 56 AND type = 46  AND strpos(message, \"prayer time(s)\") < 0 AND strpos(message, \"White days\") < 0 AND strpos(message, \"Hadith of the Day:\") < 0 AND created_time > " + facebook_check_post_Unix_Time + "LIMIT 1";

try 
{
List<JsonObject> queryResults = facebookClient.executeFqlQuery(query, JsonObject.class);
facebook_post = queryResults.get(0).getString("message");
facebook_post_visibility = queryResults.get(0).getString("timeline_visibility");
}
catch (FacebookException e){logger.warn("Unexpected error", e); logger.warn("Unexpected error", e);} 
catch (Exception e){logger.warn("Unexpected error", e); logger.warn("Unexpected error", e);}
```

**Error message:**

```
2013-12-22 07:46:35,913 WARN [javafxapplication4.JavaFXApplication4] - Unexpected error
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:638)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:414)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList.get(Collections.java:1369)
    at javafxapplication4.JavaFXApplication4$1.run(JavaFXApplication4.java:1121)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Comment: If you look at the exception traceback you can see that the error occurred on an ArrayList.get operation.  This corresponds to the `queryResults.get(0)` operation in your code, and the exception tells you you asked for a list element that did not exist.  So there is no element zero.  Ergo, your code needs to check either `isEmpty()` or `size()` on the list before accessing it and not access if there are no entries.  (The code should probably also consider the case where there's more than one entry.)  You should not have needed assistance for this -- the information is right before your eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if(!queryResults.isEmpty()) {
  JsonObject facebookPost = queryResults.get(0);
  String message = facebookPost.getString("message");
  if(null != message && !"".equals(message)) {
    // Do whatever you're trying to do with the message here
  }
  // Follow the same pattern for timeline_visibility
}
```

You're getting the exception because you're blindly trying to call a method on an object you don't even know exists:

```
facebook_post = queryResults.get(0).getString("message");
```

Comment: He's getting the exception because he's trying to *fetch* an element that doesn't exist.  If he somehow tried to call a method on it he'd presumably get a NullPointerException.  The point is that there is no element zero in queryResults -- if you check `size()` is will return zero.

Comment: @HotLicks That's exactly my point. The "if(!queryResults.isEmpty())" at Line 1 of my code block prevents this from happening.